# Are there any recommended typing methods when you use a lot of parentheses?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

It's awkward to type a lot of parentheses for me, as in `()`. `[]` `{}` come a little more naturally. Does anyone map their keys or do anything when dealing with a lot of parentheses? General tips are appreciated, and if it helps to know I use Vim regularly.

Comment: Why do the others feel more natural? And what would feel more natural?

Comment: The other keys seem more accessible with less movement. I have small hands and holding shift down with the same hand while typing parentheses causes me to have to shift my whole hand.

Comment: After typing the above comment, it seems better to just shift with my left hand and get the parentheses with my right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best advice I'd offer is to use programmer version of dvorak. It would take a little work to learn but it solves exactly the problem you are talking about.

Here is the [link](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/)

Some text editors add the closing parenthese,brackets or what have you automatically. I like this to help with the problem you speak of.

Comment: Interesting advice. I can't say I have a typing the braces on a standard layout though. I agree entirely with "having a smart editor", although in most refactoring cases I find it annoying when braces are automatically added...

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
set timeoutlen=150
inoremap (( ()<ESC>i
inoremap [[ []<ESC>i
inoremap {{ {}<ESC>i
inoremap '' ''<ESC>i
inoremap "" ""<ESC>i

inoremap <C-SPACE> <ESC>la
inoremap <S-TAB> <ESC>A
```

First part lets me type fast pairs of parentheses or others, second helps to fast go outside.
You have to adjust timeoutlen to your typing speed.

For example to get:
**someMethod($a['key'])** I type **someMethod(($a[[''key**
and then Shift+tab to go to the end of line or shift+space to skip just one char. For me its a bit easier.